# Jest dynamically adjust coverage threshold

Tags: javascript, jestjs, frontend, ts-jest

I have added jest to my teams frontend development pipeline. Right now the coverage is really low, about 1.2%, and the goal is to make sure we keep growing -- E.g with every commit code coverage at least does not decrease.

I was able to set up jest to check code coverage

```
collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    ],
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            "statements": 1.26,
            "branches": 1.32,
            "functions": 1.1,
            "lines": 1.25,
        },
    },
```

but as you can see those values are static, and I would have to manually update them as we improve our coverage.

Is there a way to tell jest to check that the new code coverage is better than the one before the changes being pushed ?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am looking to do the exact same thing

Comment: I believe that ideally, we should give more upvotes to this issue - https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/3710 so that it can be implemented in the Jest library itself.

Comment: I ended up using a tool that blocks PRs from being merged if the PR lowers coverage, or if at least X% of the code isn't covered. The tool is internal to my company, but I bet there is one for GitHub as well. I found this to be even better than setting it in jest so those rules can be skipped if there is a reason to -- high severity time sensitive bug fix, or good reasoning why unit tests don't provide value for the code in question